# Add tiles in the app launch

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, 2019, applauncher

Is it possible to add other tiles besides newsfeed, OneDrive, sites in the app launch in the above blue bar in SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short,** **Yes** can add your own **custom tiles** that point to other SharePoint sites, External links...etc.

> **Note:** Your farm must be patched with at least `Feature Pack 1`

---

**To add custom tiles in APP launcher**

- Open SharePoint Shell.
- Run the below cmdlets.

**Cmdlets**

```
Get-SPFeature -Identity CustomTiles

Enable-SPFeature -Identity CustomTiles -Url http://web_app -Force
```

- Browse to `http://web_app/lists/custom tiles` and add your tiles!

> **Note:** After you add a new item in the custom tiles list due to caching, it may take up to **24** hours before you can see it appear in
>   the app launcher. If you want to see it immediately, you can run
>   **ClearSuiteLinksCache()** function in the F12 console

**For more details,** check  [Custom Tiles in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I can add new custom tiles now, but it is not displayed in the app launcher yet!!

Comment: Please check my updated answer!

Comment: Yes, it worked for me , after 24 hour worked for all, thank you!